# Saving a document in WYSIWYG html editor(nicedit)

Tags: html, web-applications, web

I'm building an online app where you can create/edit documents in a WYSIWYG html editor(I'm using nicedit) and save it on the server.

Now, how can I save the contents in the editor? 
I have a choice to save it as html type document but I can't save the images added through url(from any other site) to editor(nicedit) permanently because it uses  tag to. Also, I'm not getting any good way to convert the image to dataurl so that it can be permanently added to  tag.

Please help!

Comment: _Why_ can't you download and convert those referenced images?

Comment: @arkascha It is not allowed in many browsers like chrome to download using javascript and convert to datauri. It is required to convert to datauri so that I can just put datauri in the src attributes of images and make them permanent in the document.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not allowed"? And I am pretty sure that no one can prevent you converting some string to base64 as you have to do to use content as a "datauri". Anyway: so you want to say you want to do all that strictly on the client side?

Comment: @arkascha Downloading from cross domain is not allowed in javascript. It gives a security error. Also, using the crossDomain="anonymous" too fails in chrome.

Comment: Sure, that is true if your page is loaded via http. But in that case you can't reference pictures at all, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @arkascha Not necessarily on client side. If you have some idea, please show me some path.

Comment: Save the html markup by uploading it via ajax to some server. That server _can_ evaluate the references, download and convert the pics and return a "converted" html structure holding the datauri versions of the pictures. PHP probably is the language of choice for that in the server side.

Comment: @arkascha No, the javascripts in nicedit.js allows to add images in the document by adding a img tag and the images are displayed as usual but the images won't show in the editor if the sever(in the url from where the image was used) removes the image.

Comment: Sorry, can't follow there. Why should a server "remove the image"?

Comment: @arkascha Btw, thankyou I'll use it if I do not get any way on client side.

Comment: @arkascha please first of all have a look at adding images in nicedit(along with its way of adding images). http://nicedit.com